How to move x-axis on top of the plot in plotnine?
I am using plotnine with a date x-axis plot and want to put x-axis date values on top of the chart but couldn't find a way to do it.
I have seen in ggplot it can be done using scale_x_discrete(position = "top")  but with scale_x_datetime() I couldn't find any position parameter in plotnine.
Below is the sample code:
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

# Create a sample dataset
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31',freq="M"),
    'value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
})

# Create the line chart
(ggplot(data, aes(x='date', y='value')) + 
    geom_line() + 
    labs(title='Line Chart with Dates on X-Axis', x='Date', y='Value') + 
    theme_classic()
)

Would really appreciate any help !!
Update (facet plot) after the answer:
# sample dataset
new_data = {
    'date': pd.date_range('2022-01-01', periods=8, freq="ME"),
    'parent_category': ['Electronics', 'Electronics', 'Fashion', 'Fashion', 'Home Goods', 'Electronics', 'Fashion','Electronics'],
    'child_category': ['Smartphones', 'Laptops', 'Shirts', 'Pants', 'Kitchenware','Laptops', 'Shirts', 'Smartphones']
}

# Create DataFrame
new_data = pd.DataFrame(new_data)

new_data

plot with answer tips
(ggplot(new_data, aes(x="date", y="child_category", group="child_category")) +
    geom_line(size=1, color="pink") +
    geom_point(size=3, color="grey") +
    facet_wrap("parent_category", ncol=1, scales="free_y") +
    theme_538() +
    theme(axis_text_x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1),
          panel_grid_major=element_blank(),
          figure_size=(8, 6),
          axis_line_x=element_line(position=('axes',1)))
)


In facet plot it doesn't go to top of the chart.

Try this:
# Create the line chart
(ggplot(data, aes(x='date', y='value')) + 
    geom_line() + 
    labs(title='Line Chart with Dates on X-Axis', x='Date', y='Value') + 
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(axis_line_x=element_line(position=('axes', 1)))
)

Here's the source code explanation/implementation for position=(axes, 1) for more clarity.
Update:
For the sake of completeness here's more detail on the facet plot for the updated question (all credit goes to @ViSa for figuring this out in the comments):
According to the source code of plotnine for facet_wrap:

scales : Whether x or y scales should be allowed (free) to vary according to the data on each of the panel.

And the allowed values are: "fixed", "free", "free_x", "free_y" with the default value being "fixed".
So, setting scales to free_x or free should resolve the problem shown in the image shared in the question.
facet_wrap("parent_category", ncol=1, scales="free_x")

Here's the updated image with this change:


Thanks Vikas, that was really helpful. Just out of curiosity how did you figure out this one. I couldn't find anything relevant on plotnine documentation and even their documentation shows position = "bottom" which doesn't seem to be working !!

It seems to be working fine in a general plot but not on facet plot. Do you know have any fix for that ?

Glad it was helpful. I read the source code of plotnine and its dependencies to the point where this functionality is implemented. Here are the details for('axes', 1) which is implemented in matplotlib. Regarding your second question - could you please share an example of the facet plot you are trying to draw? - I just tested it and it seems to be working fine.

Thanks for the response - I have updated the post with update section at the bottom containing sample data, plot code and plot image.

I was using scales="free_y" but I guess scales="free" works

And thanks for going into deep level details/code to figure out. Really Appreciate your efforts !!!

Thanks for figuring this out - I have added more context to the answer for completeness. All credit to you for this!
